# What is module, exception, FI and UNKNOWN in TAPL's OCaml implementation?

Tags: types, ocaml, opam, utop

I'm reading book ***Types and Programming Languages*** ([https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/tapl/)).

In it's chapter-4, ***An ML Implementation of Arithmetic Expressions***, it introduced the `info`. I downloaded it's ocaml source code ***arith.tar.gz*** here: [https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/checkers/](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/tapl/checkers/).

Here's the start of `support.ml`:

```
open Format

module Error = struct

exception Exit of int

type info = FI of string * int * int | UNKNOWN
```

I have several questions:

#### Q1

I installed utop(version 2.6.0) with latest homebrew on MacOS, installed libraries with `opam install core base`. Here's my `.ocamlinit`:

```
#use "topfind";;
#thread;;
#require "core.top";;

open Base;;
open Core;;
```

it gives me alerts:

```
utop # open Format;;
Line 1, characters 5-11:
Alert deprecated: module Base.Format
[2016-09] this element comes from the stdlib distributed with OCaml.
[Base] doesn't export a [Format] module, although the
[Caml.Format.formatter] type is available (as [Formatter.t])
for interaction with other libraries.

utop # open Base.Format;;
Line 1, characters 5-16:
Alert deprecated: module Base.Format
[2016-09] this element comes from the stdlib distributed with OCaml.
[Base] doesn't export a [Format] module, although the
[Caml.Format.formatter] type is available (as [Formatter.t])
for interaction with other libraries.
```

What's library `Format` and `Base.Format` ?  Do I still need to open them now ?

#### Q2

`module Error = struct` stuck in utop interpreter. What does this line mean ? Why it's been stuck in utop?

#### Q3

What does `exception Exit of int` mean ?

#### Q4

What is `FI` and `UNKNOWN` in `type info = FI of string * int * int | UNKNOWN` ?

Answer (score 0):

Q1: you should use `Base.Caml.Format` (or Core.Caml.Format) instead of `Base.Format` (or just drop base/core).

Q2: I think the code and the indentation is wrong and this is what is causing you troubles, usually you define a module like this:

```ml
module M = struct
  type t = ...
  let f = ...
end
```

So basically, struct is to denote the beginning of the module content. utop expects you to type what comes next.

Q3: it's to declare an exception named Exit which comes with an int, exemple of use is :

```ml
exception Exit of int

let f () = raise (Exit 1)

let () =
  try
    f ()
  with
  | Exit n -> Format.printf "exit %d@." n
```

Q4: it's a sum type composed of two "cases", FI and UNKNOWN, the first one coming with a string and two ints example of use:

```ml
type info =
  | FI of string * int * int
  | UNKNOWN

let print x =
  match x with
  | FI (s, i1, i2) -> Format.printf "FI (%s, %d, %d)" s i1 i2
  | UNKNOWN -> Format.printf "UNKNOWN"

let () =
  print (FI ("hello", 1, 2));
  print UNKNOWN
```